# how to install pyaudio python pakage on heroku through cli

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

how to install pyaudio on heroku through heroku cli 
if i give "pip install pyaudio" command on heroku cli the below error occurring

Error:
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... - \ error
  Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-vz9795ay/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpmq8ff3y9pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
   #include 
            ^~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... - error
    Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-vz9795ay/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-gdj2okkn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
     #include 
              ^~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-vz9795ay/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-gdj2okkn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vz9795ay/pyaudio/
You are using pip version 9.0.2, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Hi umashankar, your question is quite confused and thus it is hard to understand. Could you please take the time to format your question in a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question should have your effort to solve the task.  Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

you need to install `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt` from your console, then include a file named `Aptfile` in your project root, after that include `portaudio19-dev
python-all-dev` inside the `Aptfile` file, finally, you need to make a commit and run the command `git push heroku master`

You can see some more info here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt